# asp.net 4.0 site pointing to smtp server which is not in source code

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net 4.0 site which has an email facility.
I tested using one mail server, then when I put it on the customers server with the code changed to point to the customers smtp server, its as if its still looking for the old smtp server, which aint there.
There is no mention of it in the code any more, am I missing something?

- changed the code on the development machine, re-built project, sorted!  thanks *

thanks

Comment: How are you defining the SMTP settings? Can you post more info?

Comment: in the code behind its SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("Webserver01"); sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx"); sc.Send(nmail);

in the web.config its the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be defining the SMTP server settings in your Web.config, like this (instead of in code):

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="me@mydomain.com">
        <network host="smtp.mydomain.com"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

You can also specify the credentials here. And then just instantiate a new `SmtpClient` like this:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
```

It will use the configuration from the Web.config.

Comment: defined smtp in web.config (just changed the code in notepad on cutomers server) and it failed. changed it on the dev machine and re-built solution, it worked.  Maybe because its compiled again?

Comment: I can't answer that. To me, it seems like you had stale DLLs all along. But, using the config file instead should fix that issue. Once you change and save the Web.config, the application pool is recycled and the new config is automatically reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The default SMTP server is specified in Web.config.

Comment: I forgot about the web.config, browsed the site, got the error, changed the web.config, but im still getting the error. - also did an iisreset, and browsed the folders for any files with any mention of the old server

Answer (score 0):

in the code behind its
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("Webserver01");
sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");
sc.Send(nmail);

in the web.config its the same

Comment: You should add this to your question, NOT as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go into IIS7 Manager, select the site, and double-click on SMTP E-Mail icon on right-hand pane to configure email